# Jquery submit() not submitting form data to my view

Tags: javascript, python, flask, submit, wtforms

I have the following file (`app.py`) that generates a `Flask` instance and defines a few routes and declares/initiates a simple form:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, url_for
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
import wtforms as wtf
from wtforms.fields.html5 import DecimalRangeField

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'youll-never-guess'

class Form(FlaskForm):
    age = DecimalRangeField('age', default=30)
    submit = wtf.SubmitField('submit')

@app.route('/form/', methods=['GET'])
def form():
    form = Form()
    return render_template('form.html', form=form)

@app.route('/form/submit/', methods=['POST'])
def submit_form():
    return 'form submitted!'

def main():
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

where the `templates/form.html` file is as follows:

```
<form id="form" action="{{ url_for('submit_form') }}" method="POST" onchange="submitForm(this);">
  {% for field in form %}
    {{ field }}
  {% endfor %}
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
  function submitForm(form) {
    console.log(`submitting form ${form} ... `);
    $(form).submit();
  }
</script>
```

When I change the slider the console prints `submitting form [object HTMLFormElement] ...` but does not seem to call the view function `submit_form`. However, when I click the `submit` button the `/form/submit/` URL is rendered with the text `form submitted!`. **Why is this, please?**

Comment: What `"{{ url_for('form') }}"` produces is it `"/form/"`?

Comment: @stasiekz yes -- it yields `/form/`

Comment: Does your browser make a HTTP call on any changes? Check it in developer tools.

Comment: @stasiekz no HTTPs are being made except for when I press the `submit` button. I've added a minimal working example of this question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to rename submit field on the form because submit method/handler is shadowed by the name/id attribute.

```
class Form(FlaskForm):
    age = DecimalRangeField('age', default=30)
    sub = wtf.SubmitField('sub')
```

Alternatively you can add your form button directly in the template but it can't have id nor name `submit`.

Comment: What!? Why is this?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22982741/form-submit-jquery-does-not-work/22982900 submit method/handler is shadowed by the name/id attribute.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the change method has a call back function and inside this call back function, `this` refers to the current call back function scope, which doesn't have any `submit` method.

Therefore, fetch the form object using JQuery or vanilla JS as follows:

```
var form = document.getElementById("form");
$(form).submit();
```

Comment: thanks -- I've made these changes but the `$(form).submit()` method is still not calling the view function ...