# Onload submit not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to submit this form when the page loads. But for some reason it doesn't work. I checked the console for errors and nothing seems to be wrong there.

Here's the html plus javascript(added the jquery)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#new-ticket-form').submit();
});
</script>

  <form  id="new-ticket-form" action="/contact_form.html" method="post" name = "new-ticket-form"  >
        <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="100000000">
        <input type="hidden" name="fullname" value="JOhnny test'">
        <input type="hidden" name="order_num" value="123456">
        <input type="hidden" name="phone" value="347-489-4874">
        <input type="hidden" name="email" value="fake123@gmail.com">
        <input type="hidden" name="fromorderpage" value="yes">
        <input type="hidden" name="submit" value="Submit">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="label">
                    New Ticket Subject:
                </td>
                <td class="field">
                    <select name="subject_id">
                    <option value="0">Select one ...</option>';
                    <option value="123">Confirm Delivery Appointment</option>';
                    <option value="124"> Reschedule Delivery Appointment</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="label">
                    Summary:
                </td>
                <td class="field">
                    <input type="text" name="summary" value="This is a test disregard">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="label">
                    Your Message:
                </td>
                <td class="field">
                    <textarea name="usr_msg" placeholder = "This is a test disregard">This is a test disregard</textarea>
                </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
                <td class="submit" colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Submit Ticket" name = "btn_submit">  
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
```

Comment: do you have jQuery referenced correctly? The code seems fine, but may not be picking it up?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery: form not submitting with $("#id").submit(), but will submit with a 'submit' button?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303874/jquery-form-not-submitting-with-id-submit-but-will-submit-with-a-subm)

Comment: try excute the submit by the button btn_submit $( "#other" ).click(function() {
  $( "#target" ).submit();
});

Comment: @Casey Yes I did referenced the jQuery correct I put this on top <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: Seems pointless to ask, but checking.

Comment: @henriqueyah but i'm trying to submit the form when the pages onload without any clicks

Comment: That `<input name="submit">` is causing problems, to which @Mr.Singh alluded. [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303874/jquery-form-not-submitting-with-id-submit-but-will-submit-with-a-subm#answer-14175782).

Comment: check the before suggest and proib !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the hidden input field `<input type="hidden" name="submit" value="Submit">` - Then it works.

Working jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3bo4rgvw/3/

Comment: For reference, see "Additional Notes" in the [jQuery submit() documentation](http://api.jquery.com/submit/): `Forms and their child elements should not use input names or ids that conflict with properties of a form, such as submit, length, or method.`

Answer (score 1):

I have Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined. jQuery not defined,
but you can use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  document.getElementsByName('btn_submit')[0].click();
});
```

in your readyState loop.

Comment: In the question's comments, the OP stated that he has included the jQuery library although it does not appear in his posted question. Also, your code still references jQuery.

Comment: removing "submit" input name is better

Comment: yeah I felt too lazy to writte the entire readyState loop in pure javascript ;)