# .Submit() in jquery not firing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, form-submit

i am having a razor code as below

```
        @using (Html.BeginForm("OtherUpdateRequest", "Members", FormMethod.Post,
 new { name = "form1", id = "form1", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
     {
    .......
<input type="button" value="Update Members" name="update" id="update" class="btn btn-success">

    }
```

and in script area after some validation the form is getting submitted as below

```
 $("#update").on('click', function () {
......
            if (error == 0)
            {
                alert(error);
                $("#errorDiv").hide();
                $("#form1").submit();
            }
});
```

it is alerting the value of `error`. SO it is getting inside the if condition but the form is not getting submitted.

If i change the input code as below it will get submitted but i need some jquery validation so the submit can only done through jquery. Please let me know anything wrong I am doing.

```
    <input type="Submit" value="Update Members" name="update" id="update" 
class="btn btn-success">
```

Also if I place Submit() above the alert statement the alert also won't work..

```
$("#update").on('click', function () {
    ......
                if (error == 0)
                {
                    $("#form1").submit();
                    alert(error);
                    $("#errorDiv").hide();

                }
    });
```

Comment: where is that if condition? inside a submit hanlder?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303874/jquery-form-not-submitting-with-id-submit-but-will-submit-with-a-subm

Comment: @AmmarCSE event handler also not working..the same submit() is firing in other forms..here it is getting inside if submit is not firing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this

```
$("form#form1")[0].submit();
```

Comment: but if i place .submit() as first statement in if the `alert(error);` won't show

Comment: thanks bro..it worked..but can't understand why it is not firing in this form..the same is working with others.

Comment: submit don't work in array. If you access by specific index you can get the exact dom and submit work on that. You can also try `$("#form1")[0].submit();` it will also work

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81825/discussion-between-sachu-and-anik-islam-abhi).