# Unable to submit form on confirmation using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel

I am trying to submit a form using JQuery but it does not seem to be submitting. What am I doing wrong? This is my JS code: It does not log the `hello` word.

```
document.querySelector("form#myForm").addEventListener('submit', validateForm)
    function validateForm(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        var values = $('#myForm').serialize();

         $.ajax({
            url: "<?php echo route('validate') ?>",
            method: 'GET',
            async:false,
            data: values,
            success: function(data) {
                var data = JSON.parse(data);
                var text = data.text;
                var image_url = data.image;
                swal({
                    html: "<div style='text-align: left; margin-left: 10px'><strong>Preview</strong></div>",
                    showCancelButton: true,
                    confirmButtonText: "Yes",
                    cancelButtonText: "No",
                    confirmButtonColor: "#00ff55",
                    cancelButtonColor: "#999999",
                    reverseButtons: true,
                }).then((result) => {
                    if (result.value) {
                        $("#myForm").submit(function(e){
                            console.log('hello')
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
    });
    return false;
}
```

This is the `form` opening tag attributes - `<form action="{{url('test')}}" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm(e);" id="myForm" name="a-form">`

Comment: 1- First check the console and network tab in the browser. 2- If no error in console and network tab gives the 200 status, then **dd** in validate controller to make sure if form data shows

Comment: use like this `url: "{{route('validate')}}"`

Comment: @Adam I already `dd` in the controller but nothing still.

Comment: This solved my problem - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3303874/jquery-form-not-submitting-with-id-submit-but-will-submit-with-a-subm

Answer (score -1):

Since you don't see your `hello` on your console (developer tools), did you also check for any errors. It's most likely not printed due to that.

As for your code, `document.querySelector("form#myForm").addEventListener('submit', validateForm)` is basically doing the same thing as `onsubmit="return validateForm(e);"`. So it'd actually be doing the request twice. You can remove either one. Also do make sure your route is printed correctly on the `url`.

Comment: There are no errors on the console. Where else should I look for errors?